# DOM Events - Progress Indicator for Iframe location change

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dom-events

I am looking for a solution to show a progress indicator when an iframe page changes, *but prior to the iframe loading completely*.

There are 100's of pages on Stack Overflow going over the differences between *jQuery `ready()`, JavaScript `window.load`, `document.load`, `DOMContentReady`, `on('pageinit'...)`* and after reading the differences on all these various techniques I'm now a bit stuck on how to accomplish trapping the event within the iframe.

So far I have only succeeded in capturing when the iframe has changed once the DOM is built.  I would like to be able to detect when a page is about to load so I could have some sort of indicator/spinner in my header.

This is what I have so far (capturing the iframe change on the `onload`):

```
.....
<iframe id="rssID" src="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews"
   onload="blerg()" style="width: 800px; height:600px"/>
......
$(document).on('pageinit','#index', function(){
      alert('pageinit');  //gets called on first load
    
});
$(document).on('pageinit','#rssID', function(){
      alert('pageinit rssFeed'); //nothing happens.
});
function blerg() {
    var myIframe = document.getElementById("rssID");
    myIframe.onload = func;
};

function func() {
   alert("changed");
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/Gdxvs/

It would appear that `pageinit` is the correct path but I have no idea on how to trap that within an iframe.  I would prefer *not using jQuery*, but I'm not sure that is possible without huge amounts of code.

One final:  Do I need to use a `die("pageinit");`

Comment: it would be `.off("pageinit")`, but no, probably not needed.